# Laravel - Dynamic path

Tags: php, laravel-4

Apologies in advance if this is a noob question

I have a delete function in Laravel, I am having problems with the route and returning variables I need when the website is hosted externally.

I currently have the URL coded like this

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/Laravel/test/public/safesign_doc_delete/{{$file}}/{{$sector_name}}/{{$selected_sector}}">Delete</a></td>
```

I would like this url to be dynamic. I have tried the public_path() function but have had no prevail.

```
<a href="{{public_path()}}/safesign_doc_delete/{{$file}}/{{$sector_name}}/{{$selected_sector}}">Delete</a></td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `url()` for example, like this:

```
<a href="{{ url() }}/safesign_doc_delete/{{$file}}/{{$sector_name}}/{{$selected_sector}}">Delete</a>
```

You can also call link helpers:

```
{{ link_to('safesign_doc_delete/'.$file.'/'.$sector_name.'/'.$selected_sector, 'Delete') }}
```

Comment: dang - beat me by 45 seconds

Comment: Worked like a dream! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the routing system to generate urls ,and not create them by hand, it's quite easy:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing

the concept is simple:
1) create a route in the routes.php file
2) use it with the route() helper

edit:
to use a route and let LARAVEL generate the correct url , you simply have to do something similar to this (supposing that you are using blade):

```
<a href="{{route('name_of_the_route',array('parameter1'=>$value1,'parameter2'=> "value2,... ))}}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: you dont have to create route for public entities

Comment: "public entities" ?
what are you talking about? that things looks to me like an url to a controller, that thing should be solved in 2 lines of code, surely not by putting {{Request::root()}} to select the domain.

Comment: Upvoted to counteract downvote. It may have been downvoted because it does not explain that the route **needs** to have a name defined for `route()` to work. Most people do not explicitly name their routes so this solution would appear to not work whereas it's actually just incomplete. Give the route a name by supplying an array for the 2nd argument with the Controller in the 'uses' element and some unique name in the 'as' element like this: `Route::get('{stateSlug}/{countySlug}', [ 'uses'=>'EventController@listCountyLevel', 'as' => 'listCountyLevel' ] );` It will work then.

Answer (score 0):

url() is the default helper function get your hosting url which is found in the app.php under `'url' => 'http://localhost'` (or other)

This will solve your URL problem

**NOTE**

if you are worried about changing it when it goes to production don't worry.
Laravel gives you folder options where you can have LOCAL as a folder with localhost as your url and then the main app.php file can be your production settings.